# mediaelement.js display time rail glitch when switching tab

Tags: mediaelement

When i switch between tabs with included players i've got a problem with div.mejs-time-rail

u can see my example [here](http://dawtemplatesmaster.com/dev/test/test2.php).

My script is :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
        audioWidth: '100%',
        features: ['playpause','progress','duration','tracks','volume'],

    });

});
```

in this case i want a audiowidth at 100% but when i switch to tab2 div.mejs-time-rail _ width = 200px (default value) instead of adaptive value.
causing a display problem.
What can i do in this case, do you have any idea ?

Thanks for help !